# Cloudformation template fails due to S3Bucket resource already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have created an S3 Bucket, with the cloud formation, Lets Say Bucket Name is S3Bucket,
I don't want this bucket getting deleted if I delete stack, so added Deletion Policy to Retain,

Now the problem here is, If run the stack again, it complains S3Bucket name already exists.
If a bucket already exists, it should not complain.
What to do for this.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

I faced this in the past and what i did in order to resolve this is that i created a common AWS cloudformation template/stack which will create all our common resources which are static(Handle it like a bootstrap template). 
Usually i am adding in this template the creation of s3 buckets,VPC, networking, databases creation, etc.

Then you can create other AWS cloudformation templates/stacks for your rest resources which are dynamic and changing usually like lambdas,ec2, api gateway etc.

Answer (score 1):

S3 names are globally unique. (e.g if I have s3 bucket in my AWS account s3-test, you cannot have a bucket with the same name).
The only way to use same name is to delete the bucket, or retype your cloud formation template and use new cloud formation feature to import resource:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/